# Remotely enter BitLocker encryption key

Tags: bitlocker, wake-on-lan

Is it possible to remotely enter a BitLocker encryption key? Ideally I want to be able to remotely wake a PC over the network (WOL) to then RDP into it, however the boot drive is BitLocker encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but you need special equipment for this. Basically you need access to the computer console. For example some KVM switches have remote console access but they can get kind of expensive. Alternatively, you can separate your boot partition from your data partition, and only encrypt the data partition. This way the machine boots up with the unencrypted partition, then you can remote into it and type in the bitlocker password to mount the encrypted drive.

Comment: Or virtualize that server. Have the unencrypted partition run Hyper-V server, and the encrypted partition be your actual OS

Comment: @fjch1997 I agree that would work, though this was for a PC, not a server. Still possible though...

Comment: If your GPU, USB controller, and motherboard supports SR-IOV, a local user can actually access the virtual machine directly with their monitor, mouse and keyboard. It's one possible approach if you desperately need WOL and bitlocker pin...